# Passing a class and calling a method on it

Tags: java, android, class, android-fragments, instantiation

Consider a class extending `Fragment` called `MyFragmentClass` which has `newInstance(args)` implemented.

What I want to do is make a getter for anything extending `MyFragmentClass` so I can make a new Fragment via `newInstance(args)`. Something like:

```
<T extends MyFragmentClass> Class<T> getMyFragmentClass() {
    return SomeClassExtendingMyFragmentClass.class;
}
```

and then

```
public void makeNewFragment() {
    MyFragmentClass fragment = getMyFragmentClass().somehowCallNewInstance(args);
}
```

However I am having some difficulty, since I can't really pass it a `new MyFragmentClass()` as this defeats the purpose of using `newInstance(args)`, and I can't call `newInstance(args)` early if the args I want are in the class invoking the `get()` call.

I tried passing back the `.class` but I was only able to call `newInstance()` on it (no args).

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, you need fabric method to create instance from derived class. Define 'abstract' method and override it in derived class. 
For communication between Activity and fragment consider using EventBus with sticky events.

Comment: My issue is not with communicating between classes -- but rather getting the correct class from the child and then invoking newInstance(args) on it in the parent.